# Making the MATLAB editor or command window grab focus programmatically

Tags: matlab, window, focus, alert

When `Matlab` is processing code including the `plot()` command, `Matlab` will steal window focus, when `plot()` is processed. While many seem to find this behavior annoying, I find it useful as an alert telling me when the plot has been processed, and I can do something else while `Matlab` is running.

I would, however, like to have Matlab stealing window focus whenever calculations are done (`Matlab` being idle), and not just when I include the `plot()` or `figure()` command.

I have found a post about ***disabling*** the window stealing behavior of `plot()` and `figure()` ([Inhibit Matlab Window Focus Stealing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488758/inhibit-matlab-window-focus-stealing)), but not on ***adding*** window stealing behavior when calculations are done. Can it be done?

Comment: So basically what you want is to have some code that gives focus to a certain figure?

Comment: Not necessarily a figure, just focus to the Matlab editor or command window, when Matlab is idle. That way I can work in another program while matlab is running, and be alerted when calculations are done.

Comment: For alerts you could also use `beep` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make Matlab command window get focus, you can add `commandwindow` after the calculations. From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/commandwindow.html),

> `commandwindow` opens the MATLAB® Command Window when it is closed, and selects the Command Window when it is open.

To make an existing figure get focus, you can add `figure(h)`,  where `h` is the figure handle. From the [documentation](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html),

> `figure(h)` does one of the following [...]
>
> If `h` is the handle or the Number property value of an existing figure, then `figure(h)` makes that existing figure the current figure, makes it visible, and moves it on top of all other figures on the screen. The current figure is the target for graphics output.

Comment: The ´commandwindow´ does exactly what I want. Thanks! I will just have to include it in all codes. Isn't it possible to get this behavior through a Matlab setting once and for all codes?

Comment: It would be great to have Matlab automatically do that after each script or command. But I can't think of a way to achieve it

Comment: @Mace You could do `run('scriptname'); commandwindow` - not what you asked for, but probably better than editing all codes...

Comment: @Dei-Il Or override the `run` command to call `scriptname` and then `commandwindow`